# Create a trigger to limit number of rows for each employee

Tags: plsql

I am trying to create a trigger where it checks the quantity of each row before updating and displays an error message if quantity falls below 2.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER quantcheck 
BEFORE UPDATE ON equipment
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (old.quantityavailable >= 2)
BEGIN
    IF :new.Quantityavailable < 2
        THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, ' Quantity is below 2');
    END IF;
END Quantcheck;
/
```

The trigger is being created, but when I am trying to verify it or check if it works, I am getting an error and the trigger is not running correctly.

Comment: Did you have any question?

Comment: The trigger is being created, but when I am trying to verify it or check if it works, I am gettign an error and the trigger is not running correctly

Comment: error message ORA-04098

Comment: You maybe have mistyped the column name (Quantityavailable)? Execute `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER quantcheck;` to get more information on the error.

Comment: I do not see error here. In the error stack you have your exception or not? Show us the whole error message. I get this and it is ok : ORA-20001:  Quantity is below 2
ORA-06512: in "POINT_NET.QUANTCHECK", Zeile 3
ORA-04088: Fehler bei der Ausführung von Trigger 'POINT_NET.QUANTCHECK'

Comment: Works fine for me too after changing table.column to match my test table.  You must have a typo.  Don't you want to check Quantity on Inserts too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you error is that you use `old.quantityavailable`, and not `:old.quantityavailable`. 
Also I don't know if that `WHEN` is allowed.

Comment: Of course is WHEN allowed. The trigger is absolute correct.

Comment: If the trigger would be correct, there would be no error. ;-)

Comment: Read my comment above first (on the question). And you can try it.